# inner like merge in lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge, lodash

I am trying to do an object merge with lodash in node.js. The merge works great in the fact that it won't overwrite property objects that result in undefined.

However I would like the means for it to only overwrite objects that exist in the destination object. See example below:

```
var e1 = {
    name: 'Jack',
    surname: 'Root'
};
```

merge with

```
var e2 = {
    name: 'Rex',
    surname: undefined,
    age: 24
};
```

Current result:

```
{
    name: 'Rex',
    surname: 'Root',
    age: 24
}
```

result I would like:

```
{
name: 'Rex',
surname: 'Root'
}
```

So what I am trying to get is for the source object to only overwrite properties that exist in both, and only if they are not undefined.

I tried searching for other functions, but only found **merge** and **assign** to do similar things. But alas it is not exactly what I wanted.

The whole idea behind this is to build some method that will get objects fields from a web form and then bind them to a mongoose.js model object for persisting.

This is to avoid always having to manually bind each property to another object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a very convenient way to do this with lodash methods, but it's not too difficult to do using vanilla:

```
// Only loop over e1 values
for (var e1k in e1) {
    // Use e2 value if it exists, otherwise stick with what is already there
    e1[e1k] = e2[e1k] || e1[e1k];
}
```

Comment: Very nice!! Simple and effective. Could also re factor this to even drill down into child properties.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)**:

```
var e1 = {
    name: 'Jack',
    surname: 'Root'
};
var e2 = {
    name: 'Rex',
    surname: undefined,
    age: 24
};

var result = _.mapValues(e1, function (n, e) {
    return e2[e] || n;
});
console.log(result);
```